# AngularJS - API call returning [object object]

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to call a list of articles from the NPR API.  I have a working URL which returns as JSON.  However, somewhere in my controller, I'm getting lost getting the object.  When I console.log it to test, it returns as [object Object] and nothing else.  My service looks like this:

```
app.factory('nprService', function($resource) {
//call npr api
return $resource('http://api.npr.org/queryid=61&fields=title,byline,text,image,all&output=JSON...
```

and my controller:

```
app.controller('ArticleListCtrl', function($scope, nprService) {
//call the service and store as a variable
$scope.article = nprService.get();
});
```

I've tried using query to get the result, like this, but it's returning a single JSON object so that obviously didn't work.

```
//call the service and store as a variable
nprService.query(function(data) {
    $scope.article = data;
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))`.

Comment: Ok, I did that.  Here was my response:  {"$promise":{},"$resolved":false}  I don't know about promises so I don't have the faintest idea how to handle that or if I need to use a promise.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a promise construct to get at the data.  The controller code can be re-written as:

```
app.controller('ArticleListCtrl', function($scope, nprService) {
//call the service and store as a variable
nprService.get().then(function(result){
    $scope.article = result.data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I used this code and started seeing this error Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'nprService.get().then(function(result){
        $scope.article = result.data;
    })')  I looked into it but can't figure out how I might fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The $resource.get() function returns a promise. It should be used this way:

```
nprService.get().success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.article = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log(status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular 6 you can try this

```
myFunctionName(){
this.http.get(`http://www.thesoftdesign.com`)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log('data', this.data);
      });
}
```